# Return Multiple Column Counts

Tags: sql

I would like to track home page hit counts on numerous websites over multiple time periods (e.g. 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days) and am wondering what would be the best way to write the associated MS-SQL query.

Whenever a visitor accesses the home page of one of the sites being tracked, a record is added to a "dbo.PageHit" table that contains columns for an int Id, int SiteId, nvarchar ClientIp, and a DateTimeOffset.

A second table, "dbo.Site" contains, among many others, columns for an int ID and nvarchar SiteName.

I have a stored procedure that accepts 2 parameters to limit the minimum and maximum values of the site ids that I want returned (the numerical ranges are meaningful and, for purposes of this question, let's say that I pass in values of 50 and 100 and want to see the page hit counts of site ids 50-100).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PageHitsBySite_Select]
(
    @minsiteid int,
    @maxsiteid int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- TO DO:  Update this sql to return Hits7Days and Hits30Days
    SELECT SiteId, s.SiteName, 
    
    count(SiteId) as Hits24Hours, -1 as Hits7Days, -1 as Hits30Days
    FROM dbo.PageHit ph with (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Site s with (NOLOCK) ON s.Id = ph.SiteId
    WHERE DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, sysdatetimeoffset()) AND 
          SiteId between @MinSiteId AND @MaxSiteId
    GROUP BY SiteId, s.SiteName
    ORDER BY Hits24Hours DESC;
END;
```

As written, this query returns home page hit counts over a 24 hour period, but I need it to return the additional columns of page hits for 7 days and 30 days, as well.  Ideally, I'd also like to pass in a 3rd parameter to control the ORDER BY as to whether to return descending counts for 7 days and 30 days.

Should this procedure be written using a cursor with a temporary table, using subqueries, or some other means?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: can you add a table with some sample data and desired output as well?

Comment: I deleted my answer because there is some silly nuance I overlooked. If you post sample data and the data schema, then you are more likely to get a precise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to filter data from the last 30 days and then calculate PageHits count by using two CASE statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PageHitsBySite_Select]
    (
        @minsiteid int,
        @maxsiteid int
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
        -- TO DO:  Update this sql to return Hits7Days and Hits30Days
        SELECT SiteId, s.SiteName, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(DAY, -1 , SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Hits24Hours,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(DAY, -7 , SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Hits7Days,
        COUNT(*) as Hits30Days
        FROM dbo.PageHit ph with (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN dbo.Site s with (NOLOCK) ON s.Id = ph.SiteId
        WHERE 
              DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) AND 
              SiteId BETWEEN @MinSiteId AND @MaxSiteId
        GROUP BY SiteId, s.SiteName
        ORDER BY Hits24Hours DESC;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PageHitsBySite_Select]
(
    @minsiteid int,
    @maxsiteid int,
    @sortOrder NVARCHAR(15)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- TO DO:  Update this sql to return Hits7Days and Hits30Days
    SELECT SiteId,
    s.SiteName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, sysdatetimeoffset()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hits24Hours,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, sysdatetimeoffset()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hits7Days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DateTimeOffset >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, sysdatetimeoffset()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hits30Days

    FROM dbo.PageHit ph with (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Site s with (NOLOCK) ON s.Id = ph.SiteId
    WHERE SiteId between @MinSiteId AND @MaxSiteId
    GROUP BY SiteId, s.SiteName
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'Hits24Hours' THEN Hits24Hours
        WHEN @sortOrder = 'Hits7Days' THEN Hits7Days
        WHEN @sortOrder = 'Hits30Days' THEN Hits30Days
    END DESC;
END;
```